# Can a nullpointer being "dereferenced" evaluated as constexpr?

Tags: c++

I've got the following code:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename Base, typename Class>
constexpr std::size_t offsetOf( Base Class::*r )
{
    return (size_t)&(((Class *)nullptr)->*r);
}

struct X
{
    int a, b;
};

int main()
{
    char charsUntilB[offsetOf( &X::b )];
}
```

clang and g++ compile this without any issues but MSVC says that the offsetOf call can't be evaluated to a constant. Which compiler is right according to the standard ?

Comment: Evaluating a null-pointer dereference is UB. It's only possible to dereference null-pointers in *unevaluated* contexts, for example in a `sizeof` expression (which is typically how e.g. the standard [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) is implemented).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ... in theory. In practice nothing unforeseeable actually happens.

Comment: Maybe not for you, right now with your current compiler. Change some optimization flags, try with another compiler, and things might come crashing down. UB is UB, even if it currently seems to work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: There will never be a compiler that will generate crashing code here for sure.

Comment: On the other hand, considering that all three big compilers consider this a VLA, it's invalid from that point of view anyway ([compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/f49Gsnzcr)).

Comment: Isn't https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof  already constexpr on your system? Maybe get that fixed instead?

Answer (score -1):

Some programmer dude was right. It's just that MSVC++ doesn't support VLAs. If I have *-Werror=vla* I get an error with g++ and clang.
As it seems there's no way to have offsetOf compiletime-evaluateable anyay I can fulfill Some programmer dudes's compulsive desires with not dereferencing a nullptr:

```
template<typename Base, typename Class>
constexpr std::size_t offsetOf( Base Class::*r )
{
    union U
    {
        U() {}
        Class obj;
    } u;
    return (size_t)&(u.obj.*r) - (size_t)&u.obj;
}
```

Comment: Just like the original, this applies a `reinterpret_cast` and is thus ineligible for constant evaluation.

Comment: @DavisHerring: C+11-casts make some sense in a way that they're more explicitly express what dou you want to do and static_cast and const_cast constrain you what you can do, but they don't do anything different than a C-style cast most times. I don't need this child proof locks and I like the more readable code with C-style casts. The only C++11-style casts I use are static_cast to and dynamic_cast to convert between pointers to inherited types; you can do that with C-style casts also but the effect seems to be more hidden for me with these casts.

Comment: The `…_cast` operators are from C++98, and the C-style can’t do `dynamic_cast` and doesn’t respect access control.  None of this is the point, however: your choice of syntax doesn’t affect the fact that you can’t use `constexpr` with it.